# How to Link both Facebook likes and Website likes to show, Likes on both pages

Tags: facebook

I would like to find out whether this will be possible.

I have added a Facebook like button to my Website, and I have a Facebook page.
But when you view the website, you see 0 likes but on the facebook page its more than 20 likes.
I want to know whether it will be possible to link the two, the facebook page and the website so they both show the same amount of likes?

Like if its shows 20 likes on the facebook page, then it should show 20 likes on the website?

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you previously pasted in your head section the fb script looking like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= your app ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Paste the following code where you want your like button: (insert your fb page link before saving it).

```
<div class="fb-like" style="float:right; height:18; vertical-align:middle" data-href="https/www. your fb page link " data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma">
```

Comment: I have done the link, but it doesnt seem to link up the website and the facebook page likes...

Comment: You need to create a simple app, for the first script to use its ID. https://developers.facebook.com/apps - click here and create new app, then try again for the new code here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Yes I did some real digging in thee code and it seems to work now, thanks for the help guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the linking happens automatically if you have added the URL of your website in the Facebook page.

Ref:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ 
As per above link, specify the URL of your Facebook page in the href parameter of the like button.